# Cannot reference firebase data by push id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to update a post in firebase base on its id.
So I have a variable stored somewhere like this

```
var postID = -xyz1234567;
firebase.database().ref('posts').child(postID).update({
  blah: "blah",
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

but I keep getting this error that says;

> Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path:
>   "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".",
>   "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: Where is `postID` in relation to the update in your actual code? Looks like `postID` is not in the same scope.

Comment: This looks like a syntax error `var postID = -xyz1234567;` Instead of making up sample code of what you think `postID` is, post the [minimal actual compiling code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
var postID = "-xyz1234567";
firebase.database().ref('posts').child(postID).update({
  blah: "blah",
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

Or its always better to do following

```
var post = {};
post["-xyz1234567"] = {
  blah: "blah",
  foo: 'bar'
};
firebase.database().ref('posts').update(post)
```

Comment: Either option will add the post when it doesn't exist. The difference is that the second option will leave unspecified properties of the post untouched if it *does* exist already.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I completely agree with you that "Either option will add the post when it doesn't exist". But, I don't agree with your second statement. Both options do exact same thing, they will leave unspecified properties of the post untouched. The only difference is that second option makes sure the key (-xyz1234567) is of type "string" which was causing error in Jalasem's case.